# Adding select to parent through function called by succes function of ajax retriever

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

So basicly I'm gathering data from a file, this data is as follows:

```
[{"course_id":"1","name":"test"},
 {"course_id":"2","name":"test1"},
 {"course_id":"3","name":"test2"}]
```

Javascript/jquery code is as follows:

```
function createSelect(data) {
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]['course_id'], data[i]['name']);

        var select = $('<select></select');
        $(this).parent().append(select);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.note').click(function () {
        switch($(this).attr('id')) {
            case '1': id = 'getCourse'; break;
            case '2': break;
            case '3': break;
            case '4': break;
            case '5': break;
        };

        if(id != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: './functions/' + id + '.php',
                cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                    createSelect(data);
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log('error', error);
                }
            });
        };
    });
});
```

I'm working towards a function that places the data in options of the select dom object, I have the code for that already written. This is all about the select dom object not being made.

Unfortunatly, even while the data is succesfully writen in de console, the select object can not be made. Can someone please explain to me what I'm missing?

Comment: Side note: `$(this).attr('id')` is an unnecessarily long-winded and roundabout way to write `this.id`. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$('.note').parent().append(select);
```

instead of

```
$(this).parent().append(select);
```

cause `$(this)` in your function not refer to anything

Comment: Actually it contains the DOM element (a div) that triggers the whole click event.

Comment: @Smooth, Above will work if you have single `note` in case of multiple element??????

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `$(this)` in `createSelect` function, You need pass the element to `createSelect` function.

```
function createSelect(element, data) {
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var select = $('<select></select');

        //Use element
        element.parent().append(select);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.note').click(function () {
            var element = $(this); //Store this reference
            $.ajax({
                success: function(data) {
                    createSelect(element, data); //pass the element
                }
            });
        };
    });
});
```